# Vista logon gets stuck at the "please wait..." screen

Tags: windows, windows-vista, login, display

My computer is in a coma. Whenever I turn it on, it stays stuck on the "Please Wait..." screen and does nothing else, regardless of time. I have kept it on for as long as 6 hours to no avail. I have tried Safe Mode, Safe Mode with Networking, and Safe Mode with Command Prompt; they all also have the "Please wait..." problem.

At the suggestion of one website, I used a Recovery disk. It didn't work. (There is a slight possibility I used it incorrectly.)

I can't recall doing anything radically out of the ordinary in the weeks preceding all this. However, a day or two or three before, my roommate's IP had been blocked by the server, so he asked me to download a program for him. I did so, and transferred it by zip drive, but when he put it on his computer, his antivirus program flagged it as a virus, so he had me download another program which was not a virus and solved his problem. I am under the impression that as long as viruses are not opened (this was a .exe file), no harm is done in their simply being on your desktop. I never clicked it. Regardless, as soon as I heard it was a virus, I deleted it.

I have Vista Home Premium 32-bit on a Dell Inspiron 1525. I haven't installed any new programs in weeks, and I have an anti-virus program, although I'm unsure whether or not it was particularly active.

Much as I would like to simply clear the hard drive, I have several years' worth of photographs (not to mention music) which have not been backed up (a stupid move, I'll admit).

I would be extremely grateful to anyone who could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd prefer to wipe the hard drive and re-install Vista (the only sure way to be virus free!), you can use a Linux live CD ([ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) is recommended as being fairly straightforward) to access the Vista partition to back up files.

Answer (score 0):

The "please wait" screen is commonly stuck due to a window behind it waiting for confirmation (simply a "click OK" type deal). I'd recommend editing the registry from the [offline NT password and registry editor](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/) (make sure you back it up first), and turning off all of the applications scheduled to run at startup. They are found in these entries:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
```

Then Vista should boot but none of your startup programs will load. You can use the regular registry once again or `msconfig` to re-enable the programs selectively one by one. I'd recommend only enabling them if you're familiar with what program they are associated with. Less programs running on startup provides for a faster system anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions, but I actually just now fixed it by going back to a restore point using the Recovery Disk. The problem appears to have happened Friday afternoon, so I can safely assume that the problem *was* with the file my roommate requested.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at Microsoft / Sysinternals [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx). This tool will be able to show you everything that gets processed at your Windows startup and easily add/remove/delete entries.

It is basically a very enhanced version of the Startup and Services tab of Msconfig with a lot more!

Comment: Didn't see this question was over a month old :S Community must of bumped it :S